# Google Developer Console - Managing resources

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, android-developer-api, google-play-developer-api

I have created 30 Projects in google developer console. Now I am not able to create anything new. For that I have raised a request to increase the limit. Google have asked to pay 50$ to increase the project limit.

Now I feel that instead of paying 50$ I need to delete 1 project. But I am scared if this is used in any of the app.

**Question**
1. How to find the project which is not used in any of my App ?
2. How to safely delete the project which is not used ?
  [image]

Comment: @noogui  Hope you are new here.. All the questions are the questions raised when they do a their private project. Attached is just a screenshot for your reference. If you know how to find the usage by assuming a general case, you are welcomed to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid this won't be a fast process. As far as I can, the best method is:

- go to dashboard view
- choose each project in turn from the drop down at the top
- go to the dashboard and look at "enabled APIs and services" for that project
- change to a time period of 30 days
- if you see no traffic for 30 days it is probably safe to delete
- go back to "manage resources" view which is the little cog icon in the choosing project dropdown
- Press the three dots icon at the far right of the row (on the screenshot you posted)
- choose delete to delete the project
- repeat

Comment: Thanks !. This is a lengthy process as you said. It takes another 30 days to shutdown and delete. Till then I have to hold my development :(